# Get Sencha Touch Platform Name

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

```
console.log(Ext.os.Name)
```

prints the name for OS("Windows"==>in windows machine) for all browser,

But I want to know there is anyway to get the current **Platform("chrome","safari","firefox","windows","ios","ios-classic")** value based upon the theme currently loaded by sencha.

Because i need configure some of my component based on the browser also.

> I dont need Browser name or os name, i need the platform variable used
>   by sencha framework. like when we using the ios6 it will take the
>   platform parameter as ios-classic we also pass the platform parameter
>   in link like http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.3.1a/built-examples/kitchensink/index.html?platform=ios-classic# or
>   http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.3.1a/built-examples/kitchensink/index.html?platform=windows# this will load the ios6 and windows theme respectively even we use any kind of browser in any OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Ext.browser](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.browser)

```
console.log(Ext.browser.name);
console.log(Ext.browser.version);
```

Ext.device will not work for browser as it works only for native packing.

you can get what theme is applied by using Ext.theme.name

```
Ext.theme.name
```

getting platform for them is not directly provided in Sencha Touch. you can check implementation for that in sencha\app\microloader

Comment: I dont need Browser name man, i need the platform variable used by sencha framework. like when we using the ios6 it will take the platform parameter as **ios-classic** we also pass the platform parameter in link like http://192.168.1.242/app/?platform=ios-classic

Comment: you can get what theme is applied by using 
    Ext.theme.name
getting platform for them is not directly provided in Sencha Touch.
you can check implementation for that in sencha\app\microloader

Comment: its not working its always return Default, i think this will work only when change the theme through script at runtime.

Comment: it works for me.
<try http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.3.1a/built-examples/kitchensink/index.html?platform=windows>
Open chrome developer tools and in console try Ext.theme.name
Try changing themes by changing the platform value in browser querystring then try again Ext.theme.name

Comment: Its working,I think i missed earlier. Add this in ur Answer i will mark ur answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following configurations on http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext , from that what i have observed is, we can't find the browser's name but we can check whether it is chrome or else like that...

example :

```
console.log(Ext.isWindows); 

true //because i am working in windows

chromeVersion
firefoxVersion
ieVersion
isChrome
isFF10
isFF3_0
isFF3_5
isFF3_6
isFF4
isFF5
isGecko
isGecko10
isGecko3
isGecko4
isGecko5
isIE
isIE10
isIE10m
isIE10p
isIE11
isIE11m
isIE11p
isIE6
isIE7
isIE7m
isIE7p
isIE8
isIE8m
isIE8p
isIE9
isIE9m
isIE9p
isLinux
isMac
isOpera
isOpera10_5   
isSafari
isSafari2
isSafari3
isSafari4
isSafari5
isSafari5_0
isWebKit
isWindows
name
operaVersion
safariVersion
```

Comment: I need this solution for sencha touch not sencha extjs

Answer (score 0):

In Sencha Touch 2.3 the [Ext.device.Device](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.device.Device) singleton will give you information on the platform and the [Ext.device.Browser](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.device.Browser) will give you information on the browser.

Comment: Ext.device.Device still return the os name linke windows in Chrome running in windows machine actually i whant to get the platform parameter used by sencha touch like ios,ios-classic,windows,etc